# The union of a sequence of infinite, countable sets is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

While reading Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, I ran into the following theorem and proof:

> **Theorem 2.12.** Let $\left\{E_n\right\}$, $n=1,2,\dots$, be a sequence of countable sets, and put
>
> $$
> S=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n.
> $$
>
> Then $S$ is countable.
>
> **Proof.** Let every set $E_n$ be arranged in a sequence $\left\{X_{nk}\right\}$, $k=1,2,3,\dots$, and consider the infinite array
>
> [image]
>
> in which the elements of $E_n$ form the $n$th row. The array contains all elements of $S$. As indicated by the arrows, these elements can be arranged in a sequence
>
> $$
> x_{11};x_{21},x_{12};x_{31},x_{22},x_{13};x_{41},x_{32},x_{23},x_{14};\dots\tag{*}
> $$
>
> If any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common, these will appear more than once in $(*)$. **Hence there is a subset $T$ of the set of all positive integers such that $S\sim T$, which shows that $S$ is at most countable.** Since $E_1\subset S$, and $E_1$ is infinite, $S$ is infinite, and thus countable. $\blacksquare$

How does the bolded sentence follow from all previous? In fact, I do not know how the matrix and $(*)$ come into play.

Comment: The sequence is an onto map $\mathbb N\to S$. By considering a suitable subset $T$ of $\mathbb N$ (i.e. removing duplicates) the (restricted) map becomes bijective.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, how did you conclude that $\mathbb N\to S$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the sequence *

$x_{11};x_{21},x_{12};x_{31},x_{22},x_{13};x_{41},x_{32},x_{23},x_{14};…$

Within each ;; add the suffixes.

1+1 =2

2+1 = 1+2 = 3

1+3 = 2+2 = 3+1 = 4

and so on.

So for any positive integer you shall get a countable (finite) number of such combination and in each case you shall get elements of $S$. If you remove duplicate items then you shall get a set $S$. This set will be bijective with the set of natural numbers as for each natural number you shall get only a finite number of elements.

I hope it is clear now. The bold sequence is constructed by taking arrows in the matrix. In the matrix the elements of the set $E_i$ are written in arrow.

Comment: But N is set of all positive integers. So to which term of the sequence does 1 correspond to? I mean the least sum is 2 so our sequence starts from x2 instead of x1.

Comment: @MayankJha Guess that's why in the original text Rudin says "Hence there is a **subset** $T$ of the set of all positive integers such that $S\sim T$"

Answer (score 0):

This does not address your specific question, but mapping injectively into powers of primes is a cute trick I always enjoy sharing.

Let $x_{ij}$ be the $i$th element of the $j$th set (the same indexing scheme you are using). The function defined by $f(x_{ij}) = 2^i3^j$ is an injection into the natural numbers, so there are countably-many $x$'s in total.